# WPF C# Ellipse Grid Positioning

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, ellipse

I was wondering if it was possible to change the centre position of a circle/ ellipse when the Ellipse is on a grid layout. I can only seem to find solutions in XAML where as I need to find a C# code-behind version. If you could help that would be much appreciated.
Please see a snippet of my current circle code: https://gyazo.com/7a519a5006d4837cb4e6ec5b3a35a388

Comment: post the code in text

Comment: also post the XAML that you found which does what you want. I'm pretty sure anything in XAML is also possible in the code behind. Probably name your ellipse and then you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RenderTrasformOrigin` property.
 In this case:
`Circle.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(x,y);`
More information here [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx).